# How to add table from database my SQL in laravel 6/7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6.2

i wanna ask how to add get data from `ProdukTable` as `p_nama` into `StockTable` ?
Im using Laravel 6.2 instead. what should i do ?

> Model : **App\Produk.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produk extends Model
{
    public $table = 'produk';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pid';
    protected $fillable = [
        'pid',
        'sku',
        'p_nama',
        'p_stock_min',
        'p_stock',
        'p_harga_beli',
        'p_harga',
        'status'
    ];
}
```

> Controllers : **App\Http\Controllers\ProdukController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Produk;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;

class ProdukController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $datas = Produk::paginate(5); // 5 record per pages, silahkan disesuaikan
        return view('produk.list', compact('datas'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('produk.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'sku'           => 'required',
            'p_nama'        => 'required',
            'p_stock_min'   => 'required',
            'p_stock'       => 'required',
            'p_harga_beli'  => 'required',
            'p_harga'       => 'required',
            'status'        => 'required',
        ]);

        $data = new Produk([
            'sku'          => $request->get('sku'),
            'p_nama'       => $request->get('p_nama'),
            'p_stock_min'  => $request->get('p_stock_min'),
            'p_stock'      => $request->get('p_stock'),
            'p_harga_beli' => $request->get('p_harga_beli'),
            'p_harga'      => $request->get('p_harga'),
            'status'       => $request->get('status')
        ]);
        $data->save();
        Alert::success('Sukses', 'Produk berhasil ditambahkan!');
        return redirect('/produk');
    }

    public function show($pid)
    {
        $data = Produk::find($pid);
        return view('produk.view', compact('data'));
    }

    public function edit($pid)
    {
        $data = Produk::find($pid);
        return view('produk.edit', compact('data'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $pid)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'sku'           => 'required',
            'p_nama'        => 'required',
            'p_stock_min'   => 'required',
            'p_stock'       => 'required',
            'p_harga_beli'  => 'required',
            'p_harga'       => 'required',
            'status'        => 'required',
        ]);
        $data = Produk::find($pid);
        $data->sku          = $request->get('sku');
        $data->p_nama       = $request->get('p_nama');
        $data->p_stock_min  = $request->get('p_stock_min');
        $data->p_stock      = $request->get('p_stock');
        $data->p_harga_beli = $request->get('p_harga_beli');
        $data->p_harga      = $request->get('p_harga');
        $data->status       = $request->get('status');
        $data->save();
        Alert::success('Diubah', 'Data Produk telah diupdate!');
        return redirect('/produk');
    }

    public function delete($pid)
    {
        $data = Produk::find($pid);
        return view('produk.delete', compact('data'));
    }

    public function destroy($pid)
    {
        $data = Produk::find($pid);
        $data->delete();
        Alert::success('Dihapus!', 'Data ini sudah dihapus!');
        return redirect('/produk');
    }
}
```

> Model : **App\Stock.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stock extends Model
{
    public $table = 'stock';
    protected $primaryKey = 'sid';
    protected $fillable = [
        'sid',
        'mesin',
        'sku',
        'p_nama',
        'stock_min',
        'stock',
        'status'
    ];
}
```

> Controllers : **App\Http\Controllers\StockController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Stock;
use App\Produk;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;

class StockController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $datas = Stock::paginate(5); // 5 record per pages, silahkan disesuaikan
        return view('stock.list', compact('datas'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('stock.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'sid'           => 'required',
            'sku'           => 'required',
            'p_nama'        => 'required',
            'stock_min'     => 'required',
            'stock'         => 'required',
            'status'        => 'required',
        ]);

        $data = new Stock([
            'sid'           => $request->get('sid'),
            'sku'           => $request->get('sku'),
            'p_nama'        => $request->get('p_nama'),
            'stock_min'     => $request->get('stock_min'),
            'stock'         => $request->get('stock'),
            'status'        => $request->get('status')
        ]);
        $data->save();
        Alert::success('Sukses', 'Stock berhasil ditambahkan!');
        return redirect('/stock');
    }

    public function show($sid)
    {
        $data = Stock::find($sid);
        return view('stock.view', compact('data'));
    }

    public function edit($sid)
    {
        $data = Stock::find($sid);
        return view('stock.edit', compact('data'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $sid)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'sid'           => 'required',
            'mesin'         => 'required',
            'sku'           => 'required',
            'p_nama'        => 'required',
            'stock_min'     => 'required',
            'stock'         => 'required',
            'status'        => 'required',
        ]);
        $data = Stock::find($sid);
        $data->mesin        = $request->get('mesin');
        $data->sid          = $request->get('sid');
        $data->sku          = $request->get('sku');
        $data->p_nama       = $request->get('p_nama');
        $data->stock_min    = $request->get('stock_min');
        $data->stock        = $request->get('stock');
        $data->status       = $request->get('status');
        $data->save();
        Alert::success('Diubah', 'Data Stock telah diupdate!');
        return redirect('/stock');
    }

    public function delete($sid)
    {
        $data = Stock::find($sid);
        return view('stock.delete', compact('data'));
    }

    public function destroy($sid)
    {
        $data = Stock::find($sid);
        $data->delete();
        Alert::success('Dihapus!', 'Data ini sudah dihapus!');
        return redirect('/stock');
    }
}
```

> **AddStock.blade.php**

```php
@extends('layout.master')
@section('title', 'Tambah Stock')
@section('parentPageTitle', 'Stock')
@section('page-style')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css')}}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.css')}}"/>
@stop
@section('content')
@include('sweetalert::alert')

<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="body">
                @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <br />
                @endif
                <form method="post" action="{{ route('stock.store') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="sku">SKU:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" name="sku" placeholder="SKU Barang" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="p_nama">Nama Barang:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" name="p_nama" placeholder="Nama Barang" />
                                <select class="form-control select2" name="p_name">
                                    {{-- <!-- I want to add list from product table into here--> --}}
                                    <option value="{{ $produk->id }}">{{ $produk>p_name }}</option>
                                    {{-- <!-- I want to add list from product table into here--> --}}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="status">Status:</label>
                                <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control select2">
                                    <option value="Aktif">Tersedia</option>
                                    <option value="Menipis" color="red">Menipis</option>
                                    <option value="Habis" color="red">Habis</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="p_stock_min">Minimal Stock:</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="p_stock_min" placeholder="1000" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="p_stock">Stock Saat ini:</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="p_stock" placeholder="1000" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="p_harga_beli">Harga Beli:</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="p_harga_beli" placeholder="Tulis Nominalnya saja" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="p_harga">Harga Jual:</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="p_harga" placeholder="Tulis Nominalnya saja" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="{{ route('stock.index')}}" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="zmdi zmdi-undo"></i>&nbsp;Kembali</a>&nbsp;
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><i class="zmdi zmdi-check-circle"></i>&nbsp;Tambah</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
@section('page-script')
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/momentjs/moment.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/js/pages/forms/basic-form-elements.js')}}"></script>
@stop
```

thankyou for any help.

Comment: would you explain the situation when you want to add data to this other model, though you can do it with the help of [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: So, actually I wanted to make view/stock 'create.blade.php` and 'list.blade.php' which there will be a table inside.

Inside the table I want to insert some datas that existed in `product` database, for example column `p_name` and `sku`

I know that in the future must useing method: Eloquent Relationships but I haven't figure out how to get product data that contain `p_name` and `sku` in order to insert it into table stock view list, and create stock using select2 form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to provide the select options when creating and/or editing a stock record. You could pass the `Produk` list to the view from your controller.

```php
    public function create()
    {
        return view('stock.create', ['produks' => \App\Produk::all()]);
    }


    public function edit($sid)
    {
        $data = Stock::find($sid);
        $produks = \App\Produk::all();
        return view('stock.edit', compact('data', 'produks'));
    }
```

Now `$produks` will be available in the respective views and you can populate the select options.

Comment: ErrorException
Use of undefined constant p_name - assumed 'p_name' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View: C:\..\..\..\..\resources\views\stock\create.blade.php)

Comment: <select class="form-control select2" name="p_name">
                                    @foreach($produks as $produks)
                                    <option value="{{ $produks->pid }}">{{ $produks>p_name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

Comment: There's a typo it should be `<option value="{{ $produk->id }}">{{ $produk->p_name }}</option>` there is a missing - in `$produk>p_name`

Comment: @VhanzLulz Does correction with regards to typo solve your problem?

Comment: omg, yeah typo.
so, there's another problem, the name of data didn't show on list
https://prnt.sc/vnri8q

Comment: Can you post the code rendered for the select control - you can get it from browser dev tools

Comment: Use this for the select control `<select class="form-control select2" name="p_name"> @foreach($produks as $produk) <option value="{{ $produk->pid }}">{{ $produk->p_name }}</option> @endforeach </select>`. Can't have `$produks as $produks` in foreach loop, it should be `foreach($produks as $produk)`

Comment: yes i do.
```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="p_nama">Nama Barang:</label>
                                <select class="form-control select2" name="p_name">
                                    @foreach($produks as $produks)
                                    <option value="{{ $produks->pid }}">{{ $produks->p_name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: i did, https://prnt.sc/vnsllf

but still not show on list

Comment: Whats the output of `dd($produks)` in Controller? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @VhanzLulz As per your `$fillable` array on `Produk` model it has an attribute named `p_nama` not `p_name`. Double check with the final code you have and change the `$produk->p_name` to `$produk->p_nama` if thats the attribute name.

Comment: ah, you did it. thank you for solving my problem. you made my day. thank you sir